# Using an array as a data type in an MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am creating a Project Manager sort of app for self as a learning experience. I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and will be using jQuery to as well further down the line. For now I have created the models and some mock repositories using Ninject/Moq.

Model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string[] AssignedEmployees { get; set; }

    public string[] ProjectGoals { get; set; }

    public DateTime ProjectStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime ProjectDeadLine { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Mock repository:

```
Mock<IProjectRepository> projectMock = new Mock<IProjectRepository>();
        projectMock.Setup(m => m.Projects).Returns(new List<Project> 
        {
            new Project {ProjectID = 1234, ProjectName = "Email redesign", Description = "New email", AssignedEmployees = new string[] {"Ian", "Danny", "Mikey"}},
            new Project {ProjectID = 4321, ProjectName = "Update Cart", Description = "Make cart smoother function better"},
            new Project {ProjectID = 4567, ProjectName = "New social widget", Description = "More social media buttons"}
        }.AsQueryable());

        ninjectKernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().ToConstant(projectMock.Object);
```

View:

```
@foreach  (var p in Model){
<div class='project'>
    <h3>@p.ProjectName</h3>
    <p>@p.Description</p>
    <ul class='assigned-employees'>
        <li class="employee">
        @p.AssignedEmployees
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
}
```

The problem is that all that is rendered in the view for the AssignedEmployees array is `System.String[]`. I have tried `.ToString`, `.ToArray` and I have tried making a `foreach` loop to loop through each item in the array to print them each to a separate li.

How can I get it to print all the names in the array? Is using an array for this even the best solution? I would like so that anyone using the app can assign as many employees as they want to the project, that's why I thought an array might be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a foreach loop or a for loop.  Calling `.ToString()` is just going to print `System.String[]` and calling `.ToArray()` on an array is not going to do anything

```
<ul class='assigned-employees'>
   @{foreach(var emp in p.AssignedEmployees){
       <li class="employee">@emp</li>
  }}
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul class='assigned-employees'>
   @{for(var i = 0; i<p.AssignedEmployees.Count(); i++){
       <li class="employee">@p.AssignedEmployees[i]</li>
  }}
</ul>
```

Also, I hope you are checking to see if the array exists before trying to enumerate it, else you will get a runtime exception

```
<ul class='assigned-employees'>
   @{if(p.AssignedEmployees != null && p.AssignedEmployes.Any()){
     foreach(var emp in p.AssignedEmployees){
       <li class="employee">@emp</li>
     }
  }}
</ul>
```

Comment: That returns a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the `foreach` line.

Comment: Correct, please look at my last block of code.  You are not always initializing the AssignedEmployees in your ViewModel.  You will get a NullReferenceException in those cases.  Thus, you need to check if it actually exists before you attempt to enumerate it.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I used that got it working:
`<ul class='assigned-employees'>
            @{if (p.AssignedEmployees != null)
              {
                  foreach (var emp in p.AssignedEmployees)
                  {
                <li class="employee">@emp</li>
                  }
              }}
        </ul>`